# Auto login within iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, iframe, liferay

I have a website that I'm working on, It's something like a car sharing system, user-based.
In some pages I'm using a iframe in the middle of the page to link to another website which is not in PHP (Liferay actually), so I found out it was the easiest way to include it. The problem is, everytime a user logs in, it doesn't auto login inside the iFrame as well. It's then necessary to do a second authentication which is a bit frustrating.

Here is the example pic:

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4sr25/9ct1?size=o

As you can see, I'm logged in (check upper right corner), but the iframe still shows an authentication box instead of what's supposed to.

I thought about using javascript to auto login inside the iFrame, but I'm not sure what's the most secure way to do it, since we're talking about critical data.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the "other" website also part of your system? I sounds to me as if you're talking about to different sites.

Comment: it's indeed a different website, different domain, etc, but part of the whole "system".

Comment: Authentication is usually done by cookies/sessions. You should observe the http request created by the iframe to check if the cookie containing the authentication info is sent.

Comment: the problem is, I can't do much modifications inside the iframe (aside from layout, etc) since I just have access to a limited back office. i was thinking about using javascript to use the credentials typed before on my website and do an auto login in the iframe as well. would that be an option?

Comment: It might be possible if both websites are on the same domain (otherwise cross-origin-policy will probably prevent that). Apart from that it's a really bad idea an opens up a whole lot of security issues.

Have you checked if/which cookies are beeing sent?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean about the cookies? our website is using sessions and cookies and it works well, the other one I have no idea since we didn't take part in the programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay supports external user databases (e.g. LDAP) and Single Sign On (SSO) systems. Thus, a good way to support a single log in for many different applications, is to embed an SSO system. Out of the box Liferay supports a lot of them and it's easy to implement support for more.

One way to solve this is to use an external SSO system for your PHP application as well as for Liferay: In future you'd always sign on to that system and PHP as well as Liferay would need to interface with it.

Another way, if your PHP system can't do this is to mimic an SSO system with your PHP application - e.g. have your application forward the user identity to Liferay the way any SSO system would do. Typically this can be through cookies if both servers share a domain. Also, you could do some redirects to known URLs (e.g. encrypt the user's identity in a URL) or have a server-side system that identifies the user and sets some HTTP headers for the following appservers (Liferay/PHP)

How do you do this exactly? Is there anything already available? I fear that this is too complex an answer for this question - especially as I don't know how easy it would be to embed an existing SSO into your PHP application. That's an aspect that is quite important for the choice of strategy.